# I want to display a column from 2 tables Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, controller, datatables, inner-join, laravel-blade

I have 2 tables:

teachers and users
I want to display for each teacher the name of users who is the same teacher.

I know in controller it can be done maybe with inner join:

```
$users= DB::table('teachers')
->select('name')
->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'teachers.id')
->get();
```

but in blade template i don't know how to display for each teacher, when i do this

```
<a class="ahref" href={{route('users')}}> <div class="blueDecor">

         <p style="text-transform: uppercase;"> {{$teacher->name}} </p>

        </div>
    </a>
```

and when for the {{route('users')}} :

```
   @foreach($users as $user)
```

{{$user->name}}

@endforeach

and here show for all teachers appears all of users

for example
Teachers:
when i click on Theodor to display Anna, Maria.

Theodor -----------------------> Users: Anna, Maria

Alexander----------------------> Users: Sofia, Alex, Patrick

Sarah--------------------------> Users: Rick, George

please help me:(

Comment: have you tried looking at relationships? This is pretty easy if you have idea on it.

Comment: @luiza Please accept the answer if it helps, So the question is moved out from unanswered category. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the laravel relationships to achieve this 
In your case it will be one to one relationship between the 2 Models (users and teachers).

Please go through the below link
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

You will need to define relation in both the models. Say for Example your

user table Model name is Users

teachers table Model name is Teachers

Create one relation in User

```
public function UserTeacher()
{
 return $this->hasOne("\App\Models\Teachers","id","id");
}
```

Create one relation in Teachers

```
public function TeacherUser()
{
 return $this->hasOne("\App\Models\Users","id","id");
}
```

You can access the data like below

```
$data = Users::with('UserTeacher')->get();
```

Pass the $data variable to blade file and access it like :

```
{{$data->UserTeacher->name}}
```

I have tried to create example based on the limited data available in you question, You can change it accordingly.

Comment: @luiza Always happy to help :)